Is or was there ever a US poll how many Americans support bombing Irans's nuclear facilities?
Recently:

Republican White House hopeful Donald Trump said he believed Israel should strike Iran’s nuclear facilities in response to the Islamic Republic’s recent missile barrage.
[...Biden's] “answer should have been, hit the nuclear first, and worry about the rest later,” Trump added.

(Interestingly, Trump finally agrees with Bolton on that, whom of course has himself reiterated that point recently too.)
Are or were there any polls in the US about this, now or ever before, whether Iran's nuclear facilities should be bombed, either by the US or with US blessing?

The idea has been publicly voiced for a decade if not more, so I'd be surprised it was never polled. Although old polls may not exactly reflect the current mood, they might be interesting as a baseline.

I suspect if any poll not from 2024 can be considered even as a baseline with all the scene being shaken so badly in the past year, neither ever Israel was as close to its death as it is now, nor Israel's face seems as clean as before it was, nor even Western governments were considered co-genocider by a portion of their own population. Maybe you should narrow your scope to only recent polls, I guess.

Transforming of whole world outside of America into a radioactive desert doesn't need any poll. POTUS decision is enough with or even without agreement from senate. It is not like using nuclear bombs, just ordinary bombs dropped to some NPPs.

Unsurprisingly Trump is is channeling Jared on this.

Considering that just 10 years ago, a lot of Americans were in favor of bombing a fictional country from a Disney movie, I would not put too much importance on surveys like that.

@Philipp: or maybe they just like bombing all Muslims a bit? After all the highest percentage was amond Donald Trump supporters in that poll. They might not care where the shithole is or what's called precisely. "Donald Trump had the largest percentage of supporters in favor of bombing Agrabah (41% for and 9% against) while only 11% of John Kasich fans supported the idea." And yes 19% of Democrats.

@Philipp: in the same poll: "Of those polled, 36% believe that thousands of Arabs in New Jersey cheered when the World Trade Center collapsed on 9/11."

It's extremely difficult, if not actually impossible, to isolate American's views on the specific causus belli of Iran's potential to develop nuclear capability, but the American opinion of opposing Iran in various ways is lengthy and frequently polled since Iran is such a major player in the Middle East and a key opponent to US foreign policy there.
This Harvard CAPS poll from 2023 is the most recent I can find, but one must read between the lines to arrive at an estimate of how supportive of military action the respondents are.
